# creating 2nd Frame with a class() with tkinter

Tags: tkinter

My issue is i cannot put the scroll bar inside my listbox without using grid(). i cannot use grid() unless i create a second frame. im struggling to create a second frame with using a class. below is my code that uses the class. i did not try to add def labels() into my **init** as it will throw a syntax for using grid(). i want to use grid() for my def listbox as well... so if i create a second frame i should be able to use grid() with both of those if they are inside there own frame. i hope.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/home/lubuntu/subscription_app

from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
#from subscription_app.enter import *
import tkFileDialog


class start(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()
        self.menubar()
        self.onExit()
        self.statusbar()
        self.bottom_button()
        self.listbox()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("sfgsdfsdsdfsdy")
        self.centerWindow()
        self.pack()

    def menubar(self):
        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="???")#command=)
        fileMenu.add_separator()
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)

    def labels(self):
        lbl1 = Label(self, text="Members List:")
        lbl2 = Label(self, text="Member Information:")
        lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        lbl2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

    def listbox(self):
        lb = Listbox(self, selectmode=SINGLE)
        lb.pack(expand=True, fill=Y)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        for line in range(100):
            lb.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))

    def statusbar(self):

        status = Label(self, text="preparing to do nothing", relief=SUNKEN, anchor=S)
        status.pack(expand=TRUE, side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

    def bottom_button(self):
        saveButton = Button(self, text="Save member details") ##, command=)
        saveButton.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=5, pady=5)
        addButton = Button(self, text="Add member")
        addButton.pack(side=LEFT)

    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

    def centerWindow(self):
        w = 600
        h = 500
        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2
        self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))


def main():

    root = Tk()
    app = start(root)
    root.mainloop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

below is another batch of code which does not use a class and everything is manually typed out, which displays app better. i would just rather use my top code and learn how to do things right.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/home/lubuntu/subscription_app

from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
#from subscription_app.enter import *
import tkFileDialog


window = Tk()
window.configure(bg='lightgrey')
window.title("sgdfsdfdsfsdy")
## resize screen ##
w = 600
h = 500
sw = window.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = window.winfo_screenheight()
x = (sw - w)/2
y = (sh - h)/2
window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
## text above boxes ##
lbl1 = Label(window, text="Members List:")
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Member Information:")
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
lbl2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
## boxes resize with screen ##
frm = Frame(window)
frm.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S)
window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
## member list box with scroll ##
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frm, orient="vertical")
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
listNodes = Listbox(frm, width=20, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=("Helvetica", 12))
listNodes.pack(expand=True, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=listNodes.yview)
## member details box ##
listSelection = Listbox(window, height=4, font=("Helvetica", 12))
listSelection.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E+W+N)
## all buttons ##
saveButton = Button(window, text="Save member details") ##, command=)
saveButton.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
addButton = Button(window, text="Add member")
addButton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)
deleteButton = Button(window, text="delete member")
deleteButton.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)
## status bar ##
status = Label(window, text="preparing to do nothing", relief=SUNKEN, anchor=S)
status.grid(sticky=W+E, columnspan=2)
## menu bar ##
menubar = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=menubar)
fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="???")#command=)
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit") #command=window.onExit)
   # def onExit(self):
      # self.quit()


for x in range(100):
    listNodes.insert(END, x)

for x in "ABCD":
    listSelection.insert(END, x + ": ?")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I only see one frame in your code. Where is the code for the "second frame"? Also, why do you think you have to use `grid`?

Comment: yes i tried many things to create another frame and i was just flat out doing it wrong lol. so erased it all so it was working code to post on here rather than post all my errors... also if you test second code with grid. it works really well on the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see what the problem is. If you want to create a listbox and scrollbar, and put them in a frame, that's literally all you have to do: create a frame and put a listbox and scrollbar in it.

```
def listbox(self):

    # create the frame
    lbframe = Frame(self)
    lbframe.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill=Y)

    # create a listbox and scrollbar as children of the frame
    lb = Listbox(lbframe, selectmode=SINGLE)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(lbframe, orient="vertical")

    # pack the listbox and scrollbar in the frame
    lb.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill=BOTH)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    for line in range(100):
        lb.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))
```

If you want to use `grid` just for the listbox and scrollbar, you can certainly do that. In this specific case I'm not sure it provides any benefit over using `pack`.

Comment: ahhh, thats so frustrating... i think i was thinking into it too much. it works great. thank you. also thanks for adding comments im going to compare to mine and see what i was doing.